# Why is it that _localtime32 and _gmtime32 return the same time value for a non-GMT time zone?

Tags: c++, windows, windows-server-2008-r2

My time zone is set to `CDT` in the control panel Date/Time applet.

The following code places exactly the same date and time into `pCurGmtTime` and `pCurTime`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  __time32_t t=_time32(NULL);

  tm *pCurGmtTime=_gmtime32(&t);
  tm *pCurTime=_localtime32(&t);

  // The values in the *pCurGmtTime structure are equal to the values in *pCurTime

  return 0;
}
```

I don't have the `TZ` environment variable set, but my time zone is properly configured for the system via the Control Panel Date and Time applet. This behavior seems to go against the MSDN documentation for these functions, which says that `TZ` overrides the control panel settings, but if it is absent the control panel settings will be used.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because

> Both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of gmtime, mktime, mkgmtime, and localtime all use a single tm structure per thread for the conversion.

The second call writes data to the same location as the previous one. You need to copy the data somewhere else before calling `localtime`.

Answer (score 5):

Because the pointer returned by both those calls points to the same internal structure:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf12f0hc(v=vs.80).aspx

> Both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of gmtime, mktime, mkgmtime, and localtime all use a single tm structure per thread for the conversion. Each call to one of these routines destroys the result of the previous call.

Your second call (`_localtime32()`) overwrites the values from the first call. If you were to compare the pointer values themselves you'd see they were the same.

If you use the `_s` versions as noted at the top of the docs, you won't have that problem as you have to pass in your own `struct *tm`.

Comment: hamstergene answered first, so he'll get the checkmark, but I gave you a +1 because you provided additional details on how to avoid the problem in the first place via the _s functions.

Comment: That's your choice. I might mention that it took the extra 45 seconds to provide a more complete answer ... then edit it real quick to fix a typo.

Comment: It's too bad that multiple checkmarks can't be awarded, but I can see how that would lead to abuse... If it's of any consolation, I have another related question that I am about to ask, so you can watch for it.